# Why isn't the largest character element in my 2 dimensional array printing from the inner for loop?

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make a character string that stores and prints the largest character input. Yet everytime I try to make nested loops it improperly prints or seg. faults.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define ROWS 5
#define LENGTH 1024

int main(void)
{

    char wordinput[ROWS][LENGTH]; // For storing user input while incrementing with wordcount string.
    int wordcount[ROWS]; // For storing user input to determine largest character string
    char j;

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) 
    {
        while(i < ROWS)
        {
            printf("Word %d: ", i + 1); // Add 1 to 'i' so string wordcount string is logical. i.e. Word 1, Word 2, Word 2... instead of Word 0, Word 1, Word 2...
            scanf("%c", wordinput[i][j]);
            i++;
            
                for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    wordinput[i][j] = wordinput[i][0];
                    printf("Input %s is the largest, and IT IS a palindrome!", &wordinput[i][0]);
                    break;
                }
            
        }
    
        break; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've changed the inner loop function to if statements, while loops, I've changed data types - yet everything I try either doesn't output properly or segmentation faults.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues.

First, you have a nested loop. The outer loop is iterating over `i` and the inner loop is iterating over `j`. However, you are using the same variable `i` in both loops. This is incorrect.

Second, you are using `scanf()` incorrectly. `scanf()` expects a pointer to the first element of the array. You are passing a pointer to the second element of the array. This is incorrect.

Third, you are using `wordinput[i][j]` in your inner loop. This is incorrect because `j` has not been initialized yet.

Fourth, you are using `&wordinput[i][0]` when printing the largest string. This is incorrect because you are printing the first character of the string instead of the entire string.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define ROWS 5
#define LENGTH 1024

int main(void)
{

    char wordinput[ROWS][LENGTH]; // For storing user input while incrementing with wordcount string.
    int wordcount[ROWS]; // For storing user input to determine largest character string

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) 
    {
        printf("Word %d: ", i + 1); // Add 1 to 'i' so string wordcount string is logical. i.e. Word 1, Word 2, Word 2... instead of Word 0, Word 1, Word 2...
        scanf("%s", &wordinput[i][0]);
        wordcount[i] = strlen(wordinput[i]);
    }

    int max = 0;
    int max_index = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) 
    {
        if(wordcount[i] > max)
        {
            max = wordcount[i];
            max_index = i;
        }
    }

    printf("Input %s is the largest, and IT IS a palindrome!", &wordinput[max_index][0]);

    return 0;
}
```